# Magento- new order notification email add custom field- table sales_flat_order

Tags: magento

I would like to add custom variable on new order email notification having value populated from table sales_flat_order (i.e.  heared4us ). How can I do this ?

I am using magento version 1.7.0.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add new fields to order e-mail you need to follow the following 2 steps

1) Edit  sendNewOrderEmail() function located in

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

In that function you will find following code

```
 $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
      'order'        =>  $this,
      'billing'      =>  $this->getBillingAddress(),
      'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
   ));
```

You need to add new key value pair to add new custom value

```
 $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
          'order'        =>  $this,
          'billing'      =>  $this->getBillingAddress(),
          'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
          'customvalue'  => 'This is a custom value' //New custom value
       ));
```

2) Now the second part. You need to add the custom variable to new order email template.
Just edit the template add your custom parameter name. in the example it is "customvalue".

```
{{ var customvalue }}
```

For English the order e-mail template is located in

- app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new.html
- app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new_guest.html

So depending on your language used in the website select the proper template located inside **locale** folder.

Also you can edit the e-mail template from admin by navigating to

System > Transactional Emails > New Order Email

Comment: Thanks for this. One more Question... I have custom field heared4us in table sales_flat_order , how can I retrieve same under sendNewOrderEmail() funcation to pass its value to custom field ?

Comment: in setTemplateParams() function $this is the current order object. So if you do print_r($this->getData()) u can check that all order information is there.

Comment: Tried with var_dump($this->getData()); but its having morethan 14 MB data, not able to load, Crashes firefox. Tried with log as well. Is there any way to retrieve same ? Tried with $this->getfieldname() and $this->getData('fieldname'). Both not working. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Check this post http://code.marksserver.co.uk/magento/orders/magento-get-order-details/871/ . Use $this->getId() to get the order id.

Comment: Hello, Same problem with me please any one help me.
I have display custom field value in order email.
i am using this extension. http://www.atomicpages.net/blog/2011/06/23/how-did-you-hear-about-us-in-magento-15/ Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
    $transportObj = $observer->getData('transportObject');        
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller*/
    $transport = $observer->getTransport();
    $transportObj->setData('custom_content',"custom content 123");
    return $transportObj;
```

}