# Checkout Observer Modification 1.7+

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

this is about me tinkering again to see if this modification works:

I modified the Mage/Checkout/Model/Observer.php:

```
public function salesQuoteSaveAfter($observer)
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    Start of added code --- > $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();//Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
    if(isset($post['shipping']['email'])){
        if(isset($_SESSION['emailadd'])){
            unset($_SESSION['emailadd']);
            $_SESSION['emailadd'] = 'test2@mail.com';//$post['shipping']['email'];
        }else{
            $_SESSION['emailadd'] = 'test@mail.com';//$post['shipping']['email'];
        }
    }else{
        if(isset($_SESSION['emailadd'])){
            unset($_SESSION['emailadd']);
            $_SESSION['emailadd'] = 'test3@mail.com';//$post['shipping']['email'];
        }else{
            $_SESSION['emailadd'] = 'test4@mail.com';//$post['shipping']['email'];
        }
    }   <--End of added code;
    /* @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
    if ($quote->getIsCheckoutCart()) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId($quote->getId());
    }
}
```

the problem is this code: is returning nothing which sets the session['emailadd'] = test4@mail.com

```
$post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
```

if my code is in the wrong method, how do I add a salesQuoteSaveBefore() method that is called before sending the data in the database? is there an XML to configure before doing so?

because first what I'm aiming at is just to get the input data or post data from the onepage/checkout inputs specially the shipping[email] input, don't tell me that there is none because there is:

```
<li>
            <div class="input-box">
                <label for="shipping:emailadd"><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="shipping['email']" id="shipping:emailadd" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="validate-email required-entry input-text" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <label for="shipping:emailadd"><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Email') ?> <span class="required">*</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="shipping[emailconfirm]" id="shipping:emailconfirm" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="validate-email required-entry input-text" />
            </div>
        </li>
```

all I want to get is this one single shipping[email] input, it's kinda buggy because I'm stuck with for so long already. but I can't find a way to get it's value after onepage/checkout is submitted.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is you were editing core files. This is not appreciated.
 You can get shipping email easily from controllers. Using Event Absorber is good method than over writing files. But that is hard to compare over writing .

Just overwrite the OnepageController.php at core->Mage->checkout->controllers.

Here is the code,

```
include_once("Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php");  


    class Pakagename_Modulename_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
public function saveBillingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
//            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
//            $data = $this->_filterPostData($postData);
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

            if (isset($data['email'])) {
                $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
            }
```

Here the problem is customer may use different email for shipping and billing. So you need to checkout both shipping and billing save actions.

add to session

```
$email = $data['email'];
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue($email);
```

Then here I assume that you were trying to edit order e-mail template.
1) Edit sendNewOrderEmail() function located in

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

```
$my_email = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyValue();
 $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
          'order'        =>  $this,
          'billing'      =>  $this->getBillingAddress(),
          'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
          'my_email'  => "$my_email" //New custom value
       ));
```

Then hereafter you can fetch that email like this

```
{{ var my_email }}
```

If you want edit invoice template then you should find out corresponding function to define custom email variable. That's all..!

Comment: sorry forgot to indicate, that I added it under the app/code/local. and that is the code for the billingAction, yes. which gives me the capability to retrieve under the order_*.html templates as `var order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()` ,  if I do the same with shipping where `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array());` and `if (isset($data['email'])) {
                $data['emailadd'] = trim($data['email']);
            }` then I should be able to access the email variable for shipment .getEmailadd() right? or wrong?.

Comment: Just a follow-up question, how will use that $data['email'] in shipping inside an email order template? I mean like in billing I can use this `{{var order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()}}` or `{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}` to show the customer email in the billing array, how about in shipment, you say I got the shipment email but how can I use it inside an email order template? because I can't make a session in it, and whenever I try, when I do a checkout order it redirects me back to the cart page.

Comment: Derek..I totally confused. Actually whats your point..? What you trying to do..? The code above I posted ll get an email address that customer entered during checkout..That's all..! Please explain what you trying to do..Then only I can help to you..!

Comment: What I'm trying to do is first: get the shipping[email] which is done. and the last thing is to use it as part of for example the order_new_guest.html order email template, just that. I want to use the value I got so that the admin would receive both the billing and shipping emails, and not just the billing email.

Comment: So, You want get shipping and billing email( If both are different ) address during checkout and use that in your Email templates right ..?

Comment: yes @Elavarasan, I've been at it the whole afternoon until you said I was in the wrong page. :/

Comment: Okay..No problem.. So..You need to create custom variable then assign that email value to that variable in email function. First set the email in session like this Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue($data['email']);
Then follow this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417380/magento-new-order-notification-email-add-custom-field-table-sales-flat-order
Here set the customvalue value to our session value. Thats it..! One thing is u need to know where to add this function that's all..!!

Comment: sorry2 I just said the same thing xD my Bad @Elavarasan, thanks by the way. One last thing how do I grab this one: `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShipmentEmail($data['email']); ` to add it to the custom variable?..

Comment: the session doesn't get set, why is that? is there a file that I should include or require before I can use the session code? `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingEmail('testvalue');` **don't mind the previous comment :D

Comment: Check that function has ran or not ..set the session and get that value like above I mentioned in controller file and put exit(); after that..

Comment: the running method is only this one:: `saveMethodAction()` out of the saveBilling and saveShippingAction() they don't run at all. now I found the running method, now the $data['email'] is not set::
I added this `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping', array());
            if(isset($data['email'])){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingEmail($data['email']);
            }else{
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingEmail('sessionNotSetMethodLocal');
            }`

under OnepageController.php::saveMethodAction() under local directory

Comment: it always goes to the `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setShippingEmail('sessionNotSetMethodLocal')‌​;` is my logic wrong? or condition statement wrong?

Comment: Derek, At which function you have added the session code..? In one page checkout method, if you check the radio button "Ship to this address" then the "saveShippingAction()" doesn't run, if choose "Ship to different address" then only "saveShippingAction()" could run..

Comment: but I've added it to both saveShippingAction() and saveMethodAction() and I also click the ship to different address radio button. but when I submit I made this two else condition one in shippingAction::'shippingSet' is the session value and the other is methodAction::'methodAction' I always get the methodAction instead of the shippingSet, is there something wrong with my onepagecheckout? it's weird, like you said it should be running when radio btn is selected and I filled up as always the shipping form but it's the methodAction that gets executed.

Comment: Its seems like you have missed something in your overwrite class..Just check the core files. Do same thing in core file..

Comment: I tried renaming the local so that the one it will use is the core file, but still it throws back methodAction which means it's still the saveMethodAction() that is executed other than the saveBilling and saveShipping, if you could recommend a fix regarding this one it would be great, everything is already in reach the problem left is just this. :/

Comment: and I might as well post this as another question as a concern regarding the magento functionality, because there might be others having the same concerns.